# Is BindableBase the correct conversion of Observable project from MVVMLight?

Tags: xamarin, prism

I am converting a project that implements in `Gala MVVMLight` to `Prism`. One of the models inherits from ObservableObject in MVVMLight. Is this the right way to convert this model in Prism?

```
public class SampleClass : ObservableObject
```

to

```
public class SampleClass : BindableBase
```

Convert property setters like this.

```
  public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return isActive; }
        set { Set(ref isActive, value); }
    }
```

to

```
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return isActive; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isActive, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really doesn't matter what the base class is. There is no explicit requirement that your ViewModel inherit from BindableBase for Prism to work properly. I have had several projects that use Prism for it's Navigation and DependencyInjection but that use ViewModels inheriting from the ObservableObject from James Montemagno's MvvmHelpers or from ReactiveObject from ReactiveUI, or even a custom base class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Really the only requirement is that your ViewModel work the way it needs to.

For a fairly static View this could be just a "dumb" ViewModel class that maybe has a couple of properties that are set in the constructor.

```
public class AboutViewModel
{
    public AboutViewModel()
    {
        Title = "About";
        Text = "This is a really awesome app...";
    }

    public string Title { get; }

    public string Text { get; }
}
```

For most cases though you just need a ViewModel that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. This could be through a base class like any of those mentioned here including the ObservableObject from MvvmLight, or it could implement it directly (though I generally don't suggest it).